# Insert into rows from Python into MySQL

Tags: python, mysql

I was creating queries in Python to populate rows in a local database using MySQL. 
My variable `product` is a tuple, which holds 33 values. I want to add all of these values into appropriate columns listed in a table called `roottable` (which I created in dbForge). I was getting an error in line `con.execute()`:

```
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong. I am applying the same syntax as SQlite's.
Here is my code:

```
connection = msql.connect(host = 'localhost', user = 'me', passwd = 'password', db = 'TESTDB')

with connection:
        for product in list_product:
              #Get a tuple of standardized informtaion to store in table
              product = normalize_table_entry(product)
              con = connection.cursor()
              con.execute('INSERT INTO roottable VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,\
                          ?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)', product)

             #connection.commit()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using `MySQLdb`? Unlike `sqlite3`, `MySQLdb` uses `%s` as the parameter marker, not `?`. So, in that case, try

```
sql = 'INSERT INTO roottable VALUES ({})'.format(','.join(['%s']*33))
```

---

```
connection = msql.connect(host = 'localhost', user = 'me',
                          passwd = 'password', db = 'TESTDB')

sql = 'INSERT INTO roottable VALUES ({})'.format(','.join(['%s']*33))
with connection:
    for product in list_product:
        #Get a tuple of standardized information to store in table
        product = normalize_table_entry(product)
        con = connection.cursor()
        con.execute(sql, product)
        #connection.commit()
```

---

The expression `','.join(['%s']*33)` is best understood by looking at a smaller example:

```
In [25]: ['%s']*3
Out[25]: ['%s', '%s', '%s']

In [26]: ','.join(['%s']*3)
Out[26]: '%s,%s,%s'
```

Comment: Yes, I'm using MySQLdb. Does the `%s` convert values into a string? Or could values be of any type? And if you don't mind, could you explain `['%s']*33`

Comment: The values in `product` can be of any type. The database adapter should handle converting and quoting the values to strings which are then passed to the MySQL server. `['%s']*33` evaluates to a list of 33 items, each item being the string `'%s'`. In general, multiplying a list by an integer, `n`, produces a list with n shallow copies of the original list. Try it in an interactive session and see!

Comment: So when you do `','.join(['%s']*33)`, your original list is of one element and you create 33 copies of the first element to define a new list?

Comment: `['%s']*3` is a list of 3 items, and `','.join(...)` returns a string with the 3 items joined together with commas in between. I've update the post above, demonstrating this with a small example.